# Matrix must be positive definite

Tags: matlab

The code i m using is originally for flow past half cylinder (symmetric). I need to change the geometry so that the semi circle is replaced by half triangle. When i make this change by modifying geometry coordinates i get an error as follows:

Error using ==> chol

Matrix must be positive definite.

Error in ==> ellipt1 at 35

R = chol(A); Y = R'\B; Z = R\Y;

Error in ==> demo2 at 67

```
  ZN    = ellipt1(p,t,RDZ,[],W);
```

The part of the code where this 'chol' function is used and the geometry code is shown in the figures below:

http://tinypic.com/r/ka4p6f/8

The geometry code where i changed the coordinates is also shown below:

http://tinypic.com/r/14nzd3m/8

How can i make it work or what modifications do i need to make ?

Comment: I am not really sure of what you are doing (lacking knowledge in the subject I guess, sorry), but I think that it is a valid question to ask why the matrix is not positive definite. Is this code supposed to work for non symmetric geometries?

Comment: Please post your code as text rather than an image, that makes it way easier to troubleshoot as we can copy the code to matlab.

Comment: Come on! Show some effort with your question. Just doing a screenshot isn't enough. Do you even know if your operator `A` should be symmetric? Also: I don't think there's a reason to do the cholesky factorization anyway. Why don't you just solve for `AZ=B`? Also from your image it looks like your geometry is incorrect!